# Python: how to make a function visible throughout a program

Tags: python

I have two functions like the following:

```
def fitnesscompare(x, y):    
    if x.fitness>y.fitness:
        return 1
    elif x.fitness==y.fitness:
        return 0
    else:  #x.fitness<y.fitness
        return -1
```

that are used with 'sort' to sort on different attributes of class instances.

These are used from within other functions and methods in the program.

Can I make them visible everywhere rather than having to pass them to each object in which they are used?

Thanks

Comment: It is a little-known fact that compare functions do *not* have return -1, 0, or 1 - just a negative, zero, or postive number.  Try this code for fitnesscompare instead: `return x.fitness-y.fitness`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach (to get the visibility you ask about) is to put this `def` statement in a module (say fit.py), `import fit` from any other module that needs access to items defined in this one, and use `fit.fitnesscompare` in any of those modules as needed.

What you ask, and what you really need, may actually be different...:

as I explained in another post earlier today, custom comparison functions are *not* the best way to customize sorting in Python (which is why in Python 3 they're not even allowed any more): rather, a custom key-extraction function will serve you much better (future-proof, more general, faster).  I.e., instead of calling, say

```
somelist.sort(cmp=fit.fitnesscompare)
```

call

```
somelist.sort(key=fit.fitnessextract)
```

where

```
def fitnessextract(x):
   return x.fitness
```

or, for really blazing speed,

```
import operator
somelist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('fitness'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function with `def` makes that function available within whatever *scope* you've defined it in. At module level, using `def` will make that function available to any other function inside that module.

Can you perhaps post an example of what is *not* working for you? The code you've posted appears to be unrelated to your actual problem.